# Asp.net 4.5 Routing is not working

Tags: asp.net, routes

I I have deployed a website on Server,in the developement phase I was working fine , but when I deployed it on server it shows 404 error
When I write actual aspx page name on server it shows page.. but in case of virtual page name it through an error
www.example.com/welcome.aspx is fine
but
www.example.com/Welcome  is invalid.
can you examine my configuration file and let me know where exactly I am wrong.
Thanks..

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        <add name="ConString" connectionString="Server=********;Database=***;uid=***********;pwd=*************" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"></customErrors>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="CuteWebUI.UploadModule" type="CuteWebUI.UploadModule,CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you selected appropriate version of .net framework of your application pool. In case of asp.net 4.5 it should be .net framework 4.0

Comment: Yes sir, I selected same?

Comment: did you written register routes there?